Shipping a device with a pre-loaded configuration file
I am developing an AOSP IoT device which comes pre-shipped with a number of config variables.
These config variables include shared secrets and API access codes.
These variables are unique per-device and persist across factory resets.
Currently, these are baked in at build time however producing a custom AOSP build for each device is unsustainable.
What is the best way to provision config files to these devices, post build, which persist across factory resets and is available to be read by system apps?
I read about the persist partition, however I can’t find a way to add files to this, or how to access it from system apps.
